# Array placement of Binary Tree

Tags: tree, binary-tree

I'm learning binary trees. I was practicing a question paper and came across this question which I'm not sure if the answer I had was correct, so I want to ask you guys your input on this. (Not an assignment!)

Let's say there's this binary tree:-

```
     1
    / \
   2   3
      / 
     4  
      \
       5
```

At what index in the given array [1][?][?][?][?][?][?][?][?]

will '4' be placed?

My answer I thought was at the 3rd index (if we consider the array to be 0 based) but, I was thinking that this might not be the answer. It's more complex than that given there's a lot of NULLS at certain parts of the tree.

So should the array be like :- [1][2][3][NULL][NULL][4][NULL][NULL][5]
where '4' is placed at 5th index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(NOTE: This depends a lot on how the binary tree is implemented.)

For the tree you drew and assuming that you have the tree implicitly in an array, i.e. that you put the childs of node at position `i` in the array at position `2*i+1` and `2*i+2` respectively: Yes, then 4 is going to be at index 5 (counting from 0).

However, assuming all of the above and looking at your picture you have 5 at the wrong place in the array. 5 should be at index 12.
You should have (using your notation):

`[1][2][3][NULL][NULL][4][NULL][NULL][NULL][NULL][NULL][NULL][5]`

To see this, look at the tree with the null entries there

```
            1
        /       \
     2            3
   /   \       /     \
  N     N     4       N
 / \   / \   / \ 
N  N  N   N N   5
```

Comment: Thank you! I was confused with how the answer should be but your explanation really helped remove all doubts! I'll be careful and re-calculate better with the given math equations.